# Devise: Require Admin to Activate Account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to set up devise with the requirement that the admin approves registration requests before the user can sign in.

I get the following error in my user.rb file when I try to complete the sign up form.

```
SyntaxError at /users
syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

The reference to the error is in this method:

```
   def send_admin_mail
         AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
       end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # do i need a session controller for users? I have user/registration_controller and user/omniauth controller only?


  after_create :send_admin_mail

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader



  acts_as_messageable



# --------------- associations


  has_one :account_history
  has_one :shortlist
  has_one :match_maker
  has_many :authentications
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships

# --------------- validations


# --------------- class methods


       def send_admin_mail
         AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver
       end

       def disapprove 
           self.approved = false 
         end 
         def approve 
           self.approved = true 
         end 

       def active_for_authentication? 
           super && approved? 
         end 

         def inactive_message 
           if !approved? 
             :not_approved 
           else 
             super # Use whatever other message 
           end
         end      

      def self.send_reset_password_instructions(attributes={})
          recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_errors(reset_password_keys, attributes, :not_found)
          if !recoverable.approved?
            recoverable.errors[:base] << I18n.t("devise.failure.not_approved")
          elsif recoverable.persisted?
            recoverable.send_reset_password_instructions
          end
          recoverable
        end 
      end 
  # ----  Greeting

  def sayHello(first_name)
    "Hello, #{first_name.capitalize}"
  end
```

Please can anyone help. I can't see where the error is. It's driving me batty. Thank you.

Comment: the error message points to a syntax error, and I cannot see one in this statement... we need more context

Comment: Hi Joni, I updated the question to add my entire user model. I can't see the problem. If you can, I'd love some help.Thank you

Comment: where is `send_admin_mail`? In the user model, or does it really stand on top of your user model file and is not included in the class? Also, please show the line number from the exception

Comment: Hi Joni. The line number of the exception is: AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(self).deliver, which is the statement inside send_admin_mail. That is a method in my user model.